# Making $x$ the subject of $x^3-2x+y=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to I make x the subject of this formula?

$$x^3-2x+y=1\tag1$$

My attempt:

I apply complete the square

$$(x-1)^3+y-1=1\tag2$$

$$(x-1)^3=2-y\tag3$$

$$x-1=\sqrt[3]{2-y}\tag4$$

$$x=1+\sqrt[3]{2-y}\tag5$$

but my teacher said it is wrong!

Can you please help? Thank in advance!

Comment: There appears to be some inconsistencies here. Do we have a quadratic term for $x$ or a cubic? Because you take a cube root, but if you go backwards from (2) to (1) you don't get the same thing

Comment: This is also not true, it is $$|x-1|=\sqrt{2-y}$$  for $$2\geq y$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, so in step (4) because the R.H.S is always positive, you applied the Modulus function to the L.H.S? Could you kindly provide a reference for this procedure? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You make a mistake in the first step when you attempt to complete the square. Remember: you are working with an $x^3$, not an $x^2$, and because of this, any "completing of the cube" would require an $ax^2$ term as well. Unfortunately, due to the fact that $x^3 - 2x + y = 1$ is not one-to-one, there is no easy way to rewrite your function in the form $x = f(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [formula for a cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) and find three solutions for $x$:

- $\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^2-54 y-5}-9 y+9\right)^{2/3}+4 \sqrt[3]{3}}{6^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^2-54 y-5}-9 y+9}}$
- $\frac{i \sqrt[3]{2} \left(\sqrt{3}+i\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^2-54 y-5}-9 y+9\right)^{2/3}-4 \sqrt[3]{3} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}{2\
     6^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^2-54 y-5}-9 y+9}}$
- $\frac{4 i \sqrt[3]{3} \left(\sqrt{3}+i\right)-\sqrt[3]{2} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^2-54 y-5}-9 y+9\right)^{2/3}}{2\
     6^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^2-54 y-5}-9 y+9}}$

Comment: +1, this is correct, but I imagine people are downvoting because it is very ugly and doesn't really help you learn anything other than "there exists a cubic formula"

Comment: If people will upvote (+2) for an incomplete and uninformative "answer" stating that the OP's attempt is invalid, and downvote a principled, correct method which states exactly how to solve the problem... well I don't know quite what to do.

Comment: I didn't upvote the other answer, can't speak for whoever did. However, I think your answer could be improved in a few ways. One is simply linking or including the formula you used. Another is noting that OP's cubic is what's called a "depressed cubic" (in which the coefficient of $x^2$ is $0$), which is often easier to solve than a general cubic.

Comment: For the OP, the Depressed Cubic Formula: https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/ Cubic Formula:https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/

Comment: I didnt downvote but this just gives the roots and there is no explaining that why people is downvoting the answer. Also i didnt upvote the oher answe